# Function of a random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Here is a probability density function (PDF)

```
pdfq[q_] = C q^(4 n ν - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n μ - 1)
```

$$P_q(Q=q) = C q^{4 n\nu - 1} (1 - q)^{4 n \mu - 1}$$

I'd like to find the PDF of $l$ (noted $P_l(L=l)$), which is a function of $q$.

```
f[q_] = 2 q s
```

$$f(q)=2\cdot q\cdot s$$

**What is the PDF of l?**

---

*Here is my try*

I think $f(q)$ is an invertible, differentiable and continuously increasing function of $q$ and therefore:

$$P_l(L=l) = P_q(f^{-1}(l))\left|\frac{df^{-1}(l)}{dl}\right|$$

according to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables), where $f^{-1}(..)$ is the inverse function of $f(..)$.

Calculating this with Mathematica gives:

```
In[1]:= pdfq[q_] = 
 C E^(4 n s q ) q^(4 n ν - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n μ - 1)

Out[1]= C E^(4 n q s) (1 - q)^(-1 + 4 n μ) q^(-1 + 4 n ν)

In[2]:= f[q_] = 2 q s

Out[2]= 2 q s

In[3]:= Solve[l == f[q], q]

Out[3]= {{q -> l/(2 s)}}

In[4]:= finverse[l_] = l/(2 s)

Out[4]= l/(2 s)

In[5]:= Absdfinversedl[l] = Abs[Integrate[finverse[l], l]]

Out[5]= 1/4 Abs[l^2/s]

In[7]:= pdfl[l_] = pdfq[finverse[l]] Absdfinversedl[l]

Out[7]= 2^(-1 - 4 n ν) C E^(
 2 l n) (1 - l/(2 s))^(-1 + 4 n μ) (l/s)^(-1 + 4 n ν)
  Abs[l^2/s]

In[8]:= pdfl[0.5] /. C -> 1 /. n -> 1000 /. μ -> 0.02 /. ν -> 
    0.05 /. s -> 0.1 // N

Out[8]= -1.554651720194871*10^527
```

But the result is obviously not correct as I get negative probability densities. **What am I doing wrong?** Does the problem have to do with my constant of integration $C$? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look into the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ContinuousDistributions.html) to see if your distribution is already defined.
If it is not, you can define your own distribution based on its PDF or CDF using [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html).

```
dist=ProbabilityDistribution[ C q^(4 n Nu - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n Mu - 1), {q, 0, 1}, ...]
```

(This is incomplete, you need to define the ranges of the parameters)

Whatever ranges you variables and parameters are, you could test it by obtaining  `Mean[dist]` or `PDF[dist,x]` and checking that the there are no errors.

Now you have your original distribution, you want to transform it using  [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) .

```
tDist = TransformedDistribution[2 q s, q \[Distributed] dist[Nu, Mu]]
```

Now the PDF of your new transformed distributions would be `PDF[tDist,x]`

Comment: Thank you. I have a hard time to understand how to deal with pdf in mathematica. I ask another question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63763/create-a-probabilitydistribution).

Comment: Does it also makes sense if the expression is a function of the parameters of the distributions? Something like `dist = TransformedDistribution[2 µ a, a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[µ, \[Sigma]]]` or for my example, something like `tDist = TransformedDistribution[2 q Nu, q \[Distributed] dist[Nu, Mu]]`, (where I replaced $s$ by $Nu$)? Thanks a lot!